# ruby - how to use an attributes that's populated by another method that's stubbed out

Tags: ruby, rspec, stub

I have tests where I've stubbed out an objects attribute with

```
dictionary.stub(:words).and_return
(%w{cat,dog,fish,plane,rock,dig,dug,cut,cuts,put,puts,putting,ruby,use,GO,IT})
```

This way I don't have to use the `Dictionary.load_system_dictionary` method to populate `@words` and I can just stub out the `words` method.

Now I want to test another method called `contains_word(word)`:

```
def contains_word(word)
  @words.map(&:upcase).join.include?(word.upcase)
end
```

But the problem is that `@words` is normally populated by the `Dictionary.load_system_dictionary` method but I don't want to use that, as it has 90k records, but without it's `File.open(words_file).each {|word| @words << word}` my `@words` attr isn't being populated.

If I do

```
dictionary.load_system_dictionary
```

for the real dictionary the test passes
but if I replace it with

```
dictionary.stub(:words).and_return
(%w{cat,dog,fish,plane,rock,dig,dug,cut,cuts,put,puts,puttingzaq1,ruby,use,GO,IT})
```

I get

```
Failure/Error: expect(dictionary.contains_word('IT')).to be true

expected #<TrueClass:2> => true
got #<FalseClass:0> => false
```

btw dictionary is set initially with

```
let(:dictionary) {Dictionary.new}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `contains_word` is a `Dictionary` method, you can do

```
dictionary.instance_variable_set(:@words, your_words_array)
```

[More info](http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/instance_variable_set) about `instance_variable_set`.